# How to disable a group of radio buttons if one has been selected and display an alert if one is not selected and the next button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable the rest of the radio buttons if one has been selected for a multiple-choice quiz. I tried using a forEach loop but it is skipping the forEach loop and just triggering the alert box in the else part of the if statement when I click a radio button before one is even selected. Here is the function I am working in. the `name${questionNumber}` is the way to call my radio buttons. The myQuestions is my object with all of the questions and answers stored in it. Can someone please help me figure out how to do this, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

```js
function showExplanation(questionNumber) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("explanations")[questionNumber].classList.add("show");

  if (document.getElementsByName(`name${questionNumber}`).checked) {
    myQuestions.forEach((questionNumber) => {
      document.getElementsByName(`name${questionNumber}`).disabled = true;
    });
  } else {
    alert("Please select an answer.");
  }
}
const myQuestions = [{
    question: "What color is the sky?",
    answers: {
      a: "blue",
      b: "green",
      c: "red",
      d: "yellow"
    },
    explanation: {
      correct: "Correct answer: A. blue",
      explain: `The sky may be blue today
          `,
      source: "Source: common sense"
    },
    correctAnswer: "a"
  },
  {
    question: `What color is an elephant?`,
    answers: {
      a: "blue",
      b: "grey",
      c: "black",
      d: "green"
    },
    explanation: {
      correct: "Correct answer: B. grey",
      explain: `Most elephants are grey
        `,
      source: "Source: life experience"
    },
    correctAnswer: "b"
  }
];
```

```html
<!--    START OF QUIZ-->
<div id="border" class="uk-align-center uk-width-1-2">
  <div class="quiz-body">
    <h1 class="h1-quiz">Test Your Knowledge</h1>
    <div class="quiz-container">
      <div id="quiz"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="results" class="uk-text-center uk-text-large uk-text-bold uk-margin-small-top"></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML, so we don't have to guess what this code is working against.

Comment: Also, where is `myQuestions` defined? What's in it?

Comment: I added the rest of the code you wanted to see and just put in some dummy info into the question because this a project for my job.

Comment: None of the DOM elements referenced in your javascript are present in your HTML.  While I assume that in your full application those elements are also generated by (other) javascript, you are *much* more likely to get a useful answer to your question if it contains a [mcve] representing the issue you're trying to solve.  (This does not mean include your entire application here, just a representation of the specific question you need answered, i.e. what does the DOM look like *when this function is called*?)

Answer (score -3):

### **You mean When Correct User Can Only Choose one answer and when User select one answer other's will be disabled ??**

*What is your HTML code look like ??*

Comment: Please don't use the answer space to ask questions, even when intended to clarify the question. Instead, wait until you've earned 50 reputation points and then you'll have the "[comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)" privilege.